# Loadbalance UDP traffic with session affinity and way to take servers in & out of rotation

Tags: networking, load-balancing, udp, sticky-sessions

What is the best way to go about load balancing UDP traffic among a whole bunch of servers, while keeping session affinity based on the users' IP? I need to also be able to take servers in and out of rotation for new clients, so when they join for the first time, they get put on a server in a list of available servers, and clients already connected would stay connected to their specific server. I have written the software to maintain a list, but I can't seem to find anything that would perform this functionality. If you need the context, this is to facilitate game tournaments for Minecraft: Pocket Edition, which is done with UDP traffic, I cannot change the protocol. And, because tournaments open and close, I need to be able to place players on their proper servers. Performance is also a priority, I have a program to do this but it is very bloated and slow.

Thanks for any help!

William

Comment: Modern hardware solutions like the F5 Big-IP LTM series can do this easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We us an F5 Big-IP LTM for this.  [Configuration is straightforward](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_persist_profiles.html).

Most modern hardware load balancing solutions can do this; software solutions like [Zeus](http://www.riverbed.com/products-solutions/products/application-delivery-stingray/Stingray-Traffic-Manager.html) should be able to as well.  Many cloud providers like Rackspace and AWS provide software load balancers based on Zeus or similar technologies, if you happen to be using one of these platforms.

Comment: @phonebus could you please update dead link to f5.com website. I`m also interested in this topic further.